# linear interpolation in r: replace NA in one column based on the data from another column

Tags: r, linear-interpolation

I have two variables here (`x` and `y`). I need to replace the `NA` in `y`, based on both `x` and `y`, using linear interpolation.

The sample data is:

```
df <- data.frame(x = c(1,1.15,1.20,1.75,1.83,1.86,1.95),y = c(50,NA,30,NA,NA,NA,20))
```

The desired output is:

```
df2 <- data.frame(x = c(1,1.15,1.20,1.75,1.83,1.86,1.95),y = c(50,35,30,22.67,21.6,21.2,20))
```

I've tried to write the for loops to do this, but I am not able. I also tried some existing functions, like approx... but they are not proper for my purpose. They always interpolate the `y` value based on the given `y` values only.

Your help will be very important and much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Use `na.approx`

```
library(zoo)
transform(df, y = na.approx(y, x))
```

If you use zoo series instead of data frames then it is even simpler.

```
z <- read.zoo(df)
na.approx(z)
```